# spark streaming/sparksql cache

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have one question related to spark streaming and  how to use  caching in Spark/Spark SQL.Here is my problem description.

I get json messages from Kafka, So I would like to maintain an RDD for the last 3 hours of messages , so that any time a message comes in the last 3 hours , should be appended to an RDD(probably somekind of caching, I don't know) , so that I can query incrementally the json messages like in the below code, and see the log and

```
DataFrame dataFrame=sqlContext.read.json(rdd);
dataFrame.registerTempTable("test");
dataFrame.groupBy("field").count().show();
```

I know I can use an external database and store results, and append to it as and when I get a message, but if I can do it without going out of Spark is what I am searching for.Please suggest.
Thanks
Bill.

Comment: I think you can use `DStream.window(batch, sliding)`.

Comment: awesome , that's what I was looking for , thank you.